# Spring controller never gets invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have created simple hello world application in Spring it worked just fine then I have copied same files in another project and all of sudden main (and only) controller in app never gets invoked

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TestApp</display-name>  
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- Processes application requests -->
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/appServlet-context.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>        

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

appServlet-context.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

        <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to configure as beans -->
        <!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.testApp" />

        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven />   


    </beans>
```

and HomeController

```
package com.testApp.Controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("HomeController: Passing through...");
        return "WEB-INF/Views/Home.jsp";
    }
}
```

problem is that I always get 404 error and `HomeController: Passing through...` never gets printed to console so I suspect that HomeController doesnt even get invoked

This was working fine in another project it would print `HomeController: ...` to console but I Couldn't get view displayed so after few hours of unsuccessfully trying to get this working I decided to create new project and now it seems that not even controller get invoked

Anyone know what might be the problem

Comment: most likely you are changing some folder structure or something. If you are using eclipse, use import-export to move project.

Comment: Try turning on DEBUG level logging for "org.springframework". That should tell you what URL paths are being mapped to which controllers/methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that can help you, but you should always name your packages in lowercase letters, as it can be a source of confusion, because on Windows machines because folder names will be the same for different packages (both aAA and aaa will get into one folder). Which in turn affects autoscanning in a negative way.

I had such problem with Weblogic server: beans was picked during the server startup, but after application redeployment component-scan stopped working, making some beans(controllers) to mysteriosly disappear from the working app. The root cause was that first I had a typo in package name, forcing weblogic to create the folder structure with an uppercase letter in the directory name. Everything was fixed after I have manually removed the wretched package directory(but it took a couple of days to find the source of the problem).

[Package naming convention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html)

As for the previos project - likely "WEB-INF\" (and even "\Views\") part should be removed, you can can  declare your own view Resolver specifying jsp prefix:

```
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
       <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
       <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect you're just visiting the wrong URL. Everything you've posted works fine. I put together [a sample project](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/stackoverflow/11678699-basic-springmvc) using exactly what you posted plus a trivial Home.jsp. You can try it out and see that it works with the following steps:

```
git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp
cd tmp/stackoverflow/11678699-basic-springmvc
mvn jetty:run
```

Then navigate to `http://localhost:8080/11678699-basic-springmvc/` (sorry, Stackoverflow no longer allows creating hyperlinks with "localhost" as the host). You'll see "hi there" (Home.jsp) and you'll see the message printed to the console by the controller.